# How can I count the number of instances of continuous number sequences and their frequencies?

Tags: python, regex

I have some text in a variable, `raw_text` and I want to count the number of continuous number sequences like `124` with Python. How would I accomplish this?

In addition, is there an efficient way to calculate the frequencies of each number sequence?

Comment: can you show code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to match numeric sequences. The number of matches would be the count of continuous number sequences.

A [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) would be a convenient way to get the frequencies of each match.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

raw_text = "blah123 hello9832 then32233 123"
matches = re.findall(r"\d+", raw_text)
print(f"found {len(matches)} number sequences")

counter = Counter(matches)
print(counter)
```

#### Output

```
found 4 number sequences
Counter({'123': 2, '9832': 1, '32233': 1})
```

To sort the results by frequency and break ties using the lexicographic ordering of the numeric sequences:

```
sorted_by_freq = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))
print(sorted_by_freq)
```

#### Output

```
[('123', 2), ('32233', 1), ('9832', 1)]
```

Comment: Awesome! Perfect and simple. As a quick aside, how can I find the most frequently used number in the text? If it doesn't make sense to answer here, I can open a new Q

Comment: @Shamoon See updated answer with how to count the frequency of the numeric sequencies.

Comment: Any quick way to determine which is the most frequent or order them by frequency?

Comment: @Shamoon See solution for sorting the `Counter` results by frequency and breaking ties using the lexicographic order of the numeric sequences.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a tokenizer:

```
raw_text = "tunapro1234test123"


def tokenizer(text):
    i = 0
    numbers = []
    while i < len(raw_text):

        if raw_text[i].isdigit():
            numbers.append("")

            while i < len(raw_text) and raw_text[i].isdigit():
                numbers[-1] += raw_text[i]
                i += 1

        i += 1
    return numbers

numbers = tokenizer(raw_text)
number_sequences = len(numbers)
print(numbers, number_sequences, sep="\n")
```

(same but generator)

```
raw_text = "tunapro1234test123"

def tokenizer_2(iterable):
    generator = (i for i in iterable)
    last_number = ""
    for char in generator:
        if char.isdigit():
            last_number += char

            for char in generator:
                if not char.isdigit():
                    break
                last_number += char
            yield last_number
            last_number = ""

def number_sequences(raw_text):
    return len(list(tokenizer_2))

numbers = tokenizer_2(raw_text)
number_sequences = len(list(numbers))
print(numbers, number_sequences, sep="\n")
```

OUTPUT:

```
['1234', '123']
2
```

(both codes have the same output)